# Force resize for all video content

Tags: functions, filters, hooks, videos

I'm looking for a way to force all video content on my site to scale to 100% width and I'm hoping to avoid using any additional javascript.

Is there a filter or function that I can use to accomplish this? If so how is it used? And I do not want a plugin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more information - you can use CSS to set a max width to any element.

```
iframe, object, embed {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Rachel Baker mentioned [Fitvids.JS](http://fitvidsjs.com/) in her WordCamp Chicago [presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/u/rachelbaker/p/developing-for-all-screen-sizes) last weekend. It is a Javascript plugin that writes specific code for the various video providers online.

Try the CSS solution and fall back to JS if you can't figure it out.